# Saving Multiple Models from a Single View in .Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing an application for storing school course data and I need to save 2 related models in a single view in .Net MVC, however I can't get my head around how this should be put together.

I have 2 models, Subjects and Classes, one subject can have many classes. In my view I want to allow the user to enter details for a new subject and also assign classes to that subject in a single form submit.

Example:
Subject Name
Subject Lead Teacher Name

(the fields below may be recursive if there are many classes for a single subject)
Class Name
Class Start Time
Class Teacher Name

The user would come along and enter the subject name and subject lead teacher name, followed by enter a new class name, start time and class teacher name, once they have done this they would submit the form and I need to save Subject Name and Subject Lead Teacher Name to the Subjects model and Class Name, Class Start Time and Class Teacher Name to the Classes.

1. How do I go about creating the form fields in a single view for 2 models?
2. How do I take the submitted data and save it back to 2 separate models?

If anyone can help me with this and provide some sample code that would be awesome as I am lost at the moment!

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what viewModels are for.  You create a new class in the UI and give it whatever properties you need to access in the view

```
public class SubjectClassViewModel()
{
  public string SubjectName {get; set;}
  public string LeadTeacherName {get; set;}
  public string ClassName {get; set;}
  public DateTime StartTime{get; set;}
  public string TeacherName{get; set;}
}
```

Then strongly type your view to this view model
In your controller, collect the view model and save the data to the appropriate table

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details (SubjectClassViewModel viewModel)
{
  //can't really give details here without knowing what pattern you're using for data access
  //but basically you want to
  //save viewModel.SubjectName and viewModel.LeadTeacherName to the Subject table
  //save viewModel.ClassName, etc to the Class table
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can recomend you to use a wraper; how?, yes a major class wich represents the view or form you're using and set it as your view model type, try something like this:

The Models:

```
public class person
    public property id as integer
    public property name as string
    public property status as integer
end class

public class marriage
    public property husband as person
    public property wife as person
end class
```

then in the view:

```
@Modeltype marriage

<span>Wife Name:</span></br>
@Model.wife.Name

</br>

<span>Husband Name:</span></br>
@Model.husband.Name
```

In the action we take the class marriage and get each person by separated

```
dim t_wife as person = marriage.wife
dim t_husband as person = marriage.husband

'Put save wife code here ---

'Put save husband code here ---
```